# Add Remove Update List of class in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm working on this for more than a week and quit stressed currently, 
Hope you guys can put me out of my misery. 
I welcome If you can suggest overall different approach too. Okay here we go,

I'm on a learning curve and creating a small chat app using SignalR, MVC, JSON, jquery.

I have Chatter class which contain list of ChatMsg class (Msgs). As GetData() method shows below, I'm getting my classes populated from database to a list. As you can see list of Chatter contain some variables including list of ChatMsg. This will get any changes to Table ( new chat messages).
Up to here, this is working fine. [Add part]

```
[Serializable]
public class Chatter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Open { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastMsg { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChatMsg> Msgs { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ChatMsg
{
    public DateTime MsgCreated { get; set; }
    public string MsgType { get; set; }
    public string MsgBody { get; set; }
}

public List<Chatter> GetData()
{

    Dictionary<string, List<ChatMsg>> dcm = new Dictionary<string, List<ChatMsg>>();
    List<Chatter> lcm = new List<Chatter>();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Sender], [Receiver], [Body], [MessageCreated] FROM [dbo].[Chat] WHERE [Receiver] = @Name AND [Seen] = @Seen", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", "Fan"));//Test val
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Seen", "0"));//Test val
            command.Notification = null;

            var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                List<ChatMsg> cm = new List<ChatMsg>();
                cm.Add(item: new ChatMsg { MsgCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["MessageCreated"]), MsgType = "from", MsgBody = (string)reader["Body"] });

                if (dcm.ContainsKey((string)reader["Sender"]))
                { dcm[(string)reader["Sender"]].Add(item: new ChatMsg { MsgCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["MessageCreated"]), MsgType = "from", MsgBody = (string)reader["Body"] }); }
                else { dcm.Add((string)reader["Sender"], cm); }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<ChatMsg>> pair in dcm)
    {
        lcm.Add(item: new Chatter { Name = pair.Key, Open = true, LastMsg = DateTime.UtcNow, Msgs = pair.Value });
    }
    // Updateting [Seen] = 1 here
    return lcm;
}
```

Now if this is a new instance I'm putting this list of Chatters to Session.

Each time when getData() gets new data  I'd like to check my Session["ChatHistory"] and if Parent.Name exist I'd like to update Parent and Addrange to Msgs, if not ad new parent from getData() session list.
I'm strugling on following code.

```
public string receiveMessages()
{
    if (Session["ChatHistory"] == null) Session["ChatHistory"] = new List<Chatter>();
    List<Chatter> lc = (List<Chatter>)Session["ChatHistory"];

    ChatRepository chatRepository = new ChatRepository();

    List<Chatter> c = (List<Chatter>)chatRepository.getData();

    //havent tested below
    foreach (Chatter e in c)
    {
        var temp_lc = lc.Find(n => n.Name == e.Name);// Can we avoid linq?
        if (temp_lc == null)
        {
            lc.Add(e);
        }
        else
        {
            // How to Addrange to Msgs?
        }

    }

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var t = serializer.Serialize(lc);
    return t;
}
```

1. How to Update list of class in list of class?
2. How to remove an item from list of class?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using variable names like `chatters` and `chatterHistory` instead of `c` and `lc`. It makes it much easier to read.

Try rewriting your `foreach` in `receiveMessages()` like so:

```
foreach (Chatter e in c)
{
    var temp_lc = lc.Where(x => x.Name == e.Name).SingleOrDefault();
    if (temp_lc == null)
    {
        lc.Add(e);
    }
    else
    {
        temp_lc.Msgs = temp_lc.Msgs.Concat(e.Msgs).ToList();
    }
}
```

If `temp_lc` exists, `temp_lc.Msgs.Concat(e.Msgs).ToList()` will concatenate the `Msgs` property with `e.Msgs`. `ToList()` converts it into a `List<ChatMsg>`, and then we can assign the whole thing back to `temp_lc.Msgs`.

That last step is important because `Concat()` **does not mutate** (change) the object it is called on - instead, it returns a new object that we then can assign back to `temp_lc.Msgs`.

Comment: Nate, thank you so much for quick response. Really appreciate this. Is it possible to illustrate how to remove an item from lc.Msgs (single message from a user) and lc (entire user)?

Comment: Also I found `var temp_lc = lc.Find(n => n.Name == e.Name);` is doing the same job as your code `var temp_lc = lc.Where(x => x.Name == e.Name).SingleOrDefault();` Whats the difference? Is there an advantage in your code or simply just the preference? Thanks.

Comment: You're right, `lc.Find(n => n.Name == e.Name)` is doing the same thing as `lc.Where(x => x.Name == e.Name).SingleOrDefault()`. It's mostly a matter of personal preference. The reason I like the second way is because it gives you a little bit more flexibility. `Find` always returns the result or `null`, whereas `Where` returns an expression. If you decided to refactor your code, you could easily switch out the `SingleOrDefault` call with `Any`, or `Count`, or any other LINQ extension method.

Comment: Assuming `lc` is always declared as a `List<Chatter>`, removing items is easy because we can use RemoveAll on a list: `lc.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == nameToRemove)`. RemoveAll is a mutating function, so it directly edits the list you call it on. Removing items from `lc.Msgs` is a little different: since `Msgs` is an `IEnumerable<ChatMsg>` and not a List, we can't use RemoveAll. We can, however, use Except and assign the result back: `lc.Msgs = lc.Msgs.Except(lc.Msgs.Where(x => ???))`

Comment: Final note: You should add an `Id` field to both `Chatter` and `ChatMsg` to work with these queries. It doesn't seem like a good idea to match chatters on Name. (what if two people both have the same name?)

Comment: Thanks Mate, This is very helpful. Yes actually this `Name` is a username, so its unique, There are Id fields defined for both `Chatter` and `ChatMsg`, I'm trying not to pass Ids to client.